# Why are NServiceBus second level retry messages in the retries queue not processed?

Tags: nservicebus

Any idea why messages that fail first level retries, and are then moved by the FaultManager to the SLR queue, not getting processed? I have checked the message body, it is the message I expect to be retried yet nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you have the Timeout Manager disabled.  I believe SLR requires that timeouts are enabled.

Comment: In the logs I can see the TimeoutManager is enabled by default, then disabled but I'm not sure why. I have enabled it as a feature in the EndpointConfig - any idea why would it be getting disabled?

Comment: Can you add your config and the log messages to your question?